# Java - Applet to Executable Jar Wrapping

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, jpanel

I have written a Java XML Parser as an Applet. It is looking and functioning well enough in this form.

[image: Applet]

My Question, Is if I want to run this without a browser, how Would I properly wrap it to run as an executable?

GUI.java

```
--------------


import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener 
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Parser xmlEditor;
    private String startTimeValue;
    private String endTimeValue;

    public GUI(){
        init();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GUI();
            }
        });
    }
    public void init() {

        this.setXmlEditor(new Parser("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\workspace\\XMLParser\\src\\test.xml"));

        add(new Label("Start Time"));

        startTimeValue = xmlEditor.getStartTimeValue();
        endTimeValue = xmlEditor.getEndTimeValue();


        startTime = new TextField(startTimeValue);

        add(new Label("End Time"));
        endTime = new TextField(endTimeValue);

        save = new Button("save");
        save.addActionListener(this);


        add(startTime);
        add(endTime);
        add(save);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

        System.out.println(endTime.getText());



        xmlEditor.updateStartTimeValue(startTime.getText());
        xmlEditor.updateEndTimeValue(endTime.getText());

        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(0);



    }

    public Parser getXmlEditor() {
        return xmlEditor;
    }

    public void setXmlEditor(Parser xmlEditor) {
        this.xmlEditor = xmlEditor;
    }

    TextField startTime, endTime;
    Button save;
}
```

While trying things with Swing and JFRame etc, I am not getting properly layout, or am opening multiple windows. Can anyone provide assistance? The second Panel Keeps replacing the First. Id like to really try to learn how to place multiple components inside an executable jar is the goal.

### SwingPaintDemo.java

```
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextField;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SwingPaintDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
                SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.setVisible(true);


        Parser myParser = new Parser("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\workspace\\XMLParser\\src\\test.xml");

        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        top.add(new Label("Start Time"));

        TextField startTimeField = new TextField(myParser.getStartTimeValue());
        top.add(startTimeField);
        f.getContentPane().add(top);

        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.add(new Label("End Time"));
        TextField endTimeField = new TextField(myParser.getEndTimeValue());
        bottom.add(endTimeField);
        f.getContentPane().add(bottom);



        f.pack();

    }
}
```

Comment: This `C:\\Users\\Administrator\\workspace\\XMLParser\\src\\test.xml` is a bad idea, you should NEVER reference `src` in any path, as it won't exist once the program is built and packaged.  Instead you should use something like `Class#getResource`, which will return a `URL` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` which will return a `InputStream` to the resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, where as a `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout`

Instead of rebuilding the UI in the `JFrame`, simply add an instance of `GUI` to it, since you've already defined the functionality in a `JPanel`, this makes it easily reusable.

```
public class SwingPaintDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
                SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new GUI());

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

FYI:  You should never reference `src` in any path element, `src` won't exist once the program is built and packaged.  This is also doubly concerning for applets, as applets run in a tight security model, which prevents them from accessing the file system by default.

Instead, you should be using `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream`, depending on your needs.

```
this.setXmlEditor(new Parser(getClass().getResource("/test.xml")));
```

for example.  You may need to change your `Parser` to accept either a `URL` and/or `InputStream` as well

Comment: Thanks, this is working, quick question also how would I control layout better they are all coming on the same 1 line, not below one another. Also, I am not yet sure How I will be getting the names of the xml files im not sure about the integration point for that yet from another person but is .getResource the standard best practice in general?

Comment: That's a board question, you could start by having a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).  In your case, I'd be tempted to use a `GridBagLayout`, but it is the most complex, but flexible layout manager in the JSE